# linq query inside for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I my query is some thing like,

```
var currentUsrId = Convert.ToInt16(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
var Ids = Context.audits
          .Where(i => i.usr_id == currentUsrId)
          .Select(i => new
                 {
                      profile_id = i.profile_id
                 }).ToArray();

for ( var m=0; m < (Ids.Length); m++)
{
    var Query = Context.audits
                .Where(j => j.usr_id == currentUsrId && j.profile_id == Convert.ToInt16(Ids[m].profile_id))
                .Select(j => j.profile_id).Count();

    var TotalQuery = Context.audits
                     .Where(i => i.usr_id == currentUsrId)
                     .Select(i => new
                     {
                         Id = currentUsrId,
                         count = Query
                     }).Distinct().ToArray();

    //return json(TotalQuery,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    ----strucked at this part-----
}
```

I want to send records using for loop,I strucked at how to send these values,If i use return json inside the loop, loop is executing only once

Comment: Well yes, if you have a return statement, it's going to return from the method. It's unclear what you *want* to return. A list perhaps?

Comment: for each iteration,I have to add the "TotalQuery" values to an array or some thing and after the loop,I have to write the return statement.how to add the values

Comment: I'd suggest using a `List<T>` and just adding to it on each iteration of the loop, then return *after* the loop. Note that this has *nothing* to do with LINQ, really.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
List<T> queries = new List<T>();

for ( var m=0; m < (Ids.Length); m++)
{
    var Query = Context.audits
                .Where(j => j.usr_id == currentUsrId && j.profile_id == Convert.ToInt16(Ids[m].profile_id))
                .Select(j => j.profile_id).Count();

    var TotalQuery = Context.audits
                     .Where(i => i.usr_id == currentUsrId)
                     .Select(i => new
                     {
                         Id = currentUsrId,
                         count = Query
                     }).Distinct().ToArray();

    queries.add(TotalQuery);
}

return json(queries,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```